# WAMP server 2.4 installation of joomla 2.5.14 stuck on step 4 loading image

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I saw similar questions but any of them has not correct answer. The installation of Joomla on localhost does not proceed after step 4. Database Configuration.

```
WAMPSERVER version 2.4
Apache 2.4.4
PHP 5.4.12
MySQL 5.6.12
Joomla_2.5.14-Stable-Full_Package
```

for this i tried 
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
This will open notepad on the correct php.ini file, look for this directive

max_execution_time = 60
Change it to something larger like

max_execution_time = 240

But i did n't get any response still facing installation issue

Comment: Once you changed the `max_execution_time` in the *php.ini*, did you restart Apache?

Answer (score 0):

i had unsuccessfullly tried to intstall joomla 2.5.17 on wamp 2.4. installation would get stuck in the database configuration. i changed the php.ini max execution time to 240 and the installation completed successfully (read about that in the previous answer posted). but be sure to restart wamp server after editing the php.ini file. regards for the help.